# Short String after php explode

Tags: php, explode, implode, short

HI I get a string in our data base after completing a quiz which contains the results of each question in a single string. like:

```
&q1=2&q2=5&q14=7&q6=8&q4=9&q19=10&q12=1&q20=3
```

each question can be skipped for a while to answer later, so the answers are unsorted.
now I want the results like

```
q1=2,q2=5,q4=9,q6=8,q12=1,q14=7,q19=10,q20=3
```

Can anyone help me.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$a='&q1=2&q2=5&q14=7&q6=8&q4=9&q19=10&q12=1&q20=3';
$b=explode('&',$a);
natsort($b);
$c=implode(',',$b);
print($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
$a='&q1=2&q2=5&q14=7&q6=8&q4=9&q19=10&q12=1&q20=3';
$a = ltrim($a,'&');
$b=explode('&',$a);
natsort($b);
echo $c=implode(',',$b);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$url = '&q1=2&q2=5&q14=7&q6=8&q4=9&q19=10&q12=1&q20=3';
parse_str($url, $urlDecoded);
$urlDecoded = array_flip($urlDecoded);
natsort($urlDecoded);
$urlDecoded = array_flip($urlDecoded);
var_dump($urlDecoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other examples were fine but they all had a leading comma `,`.

Here is an improved version:

```
$a=explode('&','&q1=2&q2=5&q14=7&q6=8&q4=9&q19=10&q12=1&q20=3');
natsort($a);
echo substr(implode(',',$a),1);
```